# How to create submenu in the vuetify main drawer/navigation

Tags: navigation, vuejs2, navigation-drawer, submenu, vuetify.js

I'm new to vuetify js. I've started to use it and need your help to accomplish the submenu in the right side menu. Please see attached.
I'm reffering to the one in the left with arrow down to select its contents. From here: "https://vuetifyjs.com/vuetify/quick-start"

ex. Vuetify -> (click arrow down) - > Contributing

Please let me know how to do it.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 11):

Check the documentation about lists [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/lists) and about navigation drawers [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/navigation-drawers).

On the list documentation, check example #10.This shows you expandable lists. Inspect the example code by using the `< >` button. Combine the list and navigation drawer examples and try some stuff out.

That should get you starded. Hek, that is how I started :)